# Unix Shell Scripting to calculate

Tags: unix

I have following data ;

```
24692 -rw-rw-r--+ 1 da01 da01 25284427 Aug 31 09:06 collected_BOT.227031    
24660 -rw-rw-r--+ 1 da01 da01 25248756 Aug 31 09:35 collected_BOT.227032    
24748 -rw-rw-r--+ 1 da01 da01 25338868 Aug 31 10:03 collected_BOT.227033    
24740 -rw-rw-r--+ 1 da01 da01 25331322 Aug 31 10:31 collected_BOT.227034
```

sample:

```
grep 1303 collected_BOT.227034 | more    
1559254293,151840703,AJ1X,10178801756650692,VA,VB,0,0,2,2,1303,1,L1O,6797,129,1,3,601,0,GVW1,9110,551,17,000000,0001,000000,,6,4,,1,1,,0   
1559254294,151840704,AJ2X,10178801756650693,VA,VB,0,0,2,2,1303,1,L2O,6797,203,1,3,601,0,GVW2,9110,552,17,000000,0001,000000,,6,4,,1,1,,0
1559254295,151840705,AJ3X,10178801756650694,VA,VB,0,0,2,2,1303,1,L3O,6797,664,1,3,601,0,GVW3,9110,552,17,000000,0001,000000,,6,4,,1,1,,0
```

`$15 = duration`

I just want to calculate the total amount `$15` on file `collected_BOT.227034` (only if **$11=1303**)

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F, '$11==1303{sum+=$15} END {print sum}' collected_BOT.227034
```

- `-F,` field separator is `,`
- `$11==1303` check if `11th` field exactly matches the number `1303`

  - If so, add the value of `15th` field to `sum` variable (whose initial value is zero by default)
- `END {print sum}` after processing all the lines of input file, print the value of `sum` variable

**Edit:**

Thanks @Mark Setchell for pointing out that `$11==1303` can be used instead of `$11 ~ /^1303$/`

Also, use `print sum + 0` if output is needed as '0' even when no lines match. Or an explicit `BEGIN{sum=0}` block

Comment: As `1303` is a number, I think you might be better off using `$11==1303` rather than pattern matching.

Comment: By the way, if you change `print sum` to `print sum + 0`, it will still work if the sum is zero, or there are no matching lines.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, I checked, it works even without `sum + 0`.. mine is `GNU Awk 4.1.3` does that make a difference?

Comment: I think the GNU version is more forgiving. I am using the older one shipped with Apple's OSX and it just prints an empty line at the end if no lines match.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, gotcha.. I was making the values sum to zero, if no lines match, the output is blank like you mentioned..

Answer (score 0):

Great solution @sp asic.

No need to use regular expression for field `$11` though:

```
awk -F, '$11=="1303" {sum+=$15} END {print sum}' collected_BOT.227034
```

(beware: use `==` and not `=`, because this last one will do nothing except do a (successful) assignment to field `$11`

Comment: Why the double quotes around a number?

Comment: Hi J. Chomel,

its work :) thank you very much.

explanations you provide easily understandable for me.

Comment: @GaidenSaga, if this worked, you should [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it as correct answer.